# How to associate volume drive letter with corresponding disk partitions?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, filesystems, kernel32

My goal is to associate a pair of "drive and partition number" with a logical drive letter for that volume. For instance, in this configuration:

[image]

for a spanned volume `F:` I would assume to get:

```
Volume F:
  PhysicalDrive1-Partition1
  PhysicalDrive2-Partition1
```

So to obtain physical drive numbers that the volume spans I use [IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365194(v=vs.85).aspx) control code for the `DeviceIoControl` API as [described here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/12196/) (they don't allocate memory correctly for `DeviceIoControl` API call, but that's outside of the scope of this question.)

So in my example for volume `F:` I get two [DISK_EXTENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363968(v=vs.85).aspx) structures that I can use to get physical drive numbers from, using `DiskNumber` member.

My question is how do I get corresponding partition numbers?

PS. The reason I need those partition numbers is so that I can associate volume drive letters with disk partitions in a later call to [IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365174(v=vs.85).aspx) using the drive handle that was opened as `"\\?\PhysicalDriveX"` where `X` stands for drive number.

Comment: You could read the disk's partition table and scan its entries to find the one corresponding to the `DISK_EXTENT`'s member `StartingOffset` you got for the disk number.

Comment: @alk: Almost wanted to post and say that you solved it, but then after doing some tests I realized that MS threw in another wrench in the process -- evidently `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX` does not work with dynamic disks. So those offsets don't match. Like "Disk 2" in the screenshot will appear as one partition in results returned by `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX`. Damn!

Comment: You want to say in disk 2's partition table you find one partition entry only?

Comment: @alk: Yes. Read the remarks section here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365180(v=vs.85).aspx I don't know why they chose not to support dynamic disks? It makes `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX` totally useless then. Interestingly enough, it seems that `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` supports dynamic disks. Reasoning? Evades me...